# Check if cells across is blank then hide a header vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have some data in excel with headers in column B and data from column C, starting in row 2. In row 15, it may or may not have a numerical value. My task is to check from cell C15 to the end of the last column, maybe F15, maybe Z15, that if they are blanks across, I can delete B15, the header for that row.

Now, I can't just check if all values in row 15 is blank since I have the header in cell B15. I get weekly data so that is why last column vary.

What I need is if I have data, in row 15, but not the same across, I keep my header B15, if I don't have any data or if I have the same data across. I want to delete my header, B15.

I wrote some vba codes but it's not producing desire results.

```
Sub test()
Dim LR3, z As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("wc")


 LR3 = ws.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 For z = 3 To LR3
    'start position
    If ws.Cells(15, z).Value = ws.Cells(15, z + 1).Value Then
        ws.Cells(15, 2).Value = ""
     End If
  Next z
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand your task but I tried to fix your loop. Because I thought you want to iterate through the last row starting from column c, is that right?

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim LC3, z As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim startColumn As Integer
    Dim checkRow As Integer
    Dim headerColumn As Integer
    Dim allTheSame As Boolean
    Dim allEmpty As Boolean

    Set ws = Worksheets("wc")
    LC3 = ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlToRight).Column
    startColumn = 3
    checkRow = 15
    headerColumn = 2

'    'if first column is blank delete the header
'    If ws.Cells(checkRow, startColumn).Value = "" Then
'        ws.Cells(checkRow, headerColumn).Value = ""
'        Exit Sub
'    End If
'
    allTheSame = True
    allEmpty = True

    For z = startColumn To LC3
        'if any column is blank delete the header
'        If ws.Cells(checkRow, z).Value = "" Then
'            ws.Cells(checkRow, headerColumn).Value = ""
'            'Exit For
'        End If
        'if one is not the same delete header
'        If z + 1 <= LC3 Then
'            If ws.Cells(checkRow, z).Value <> ws.Cells(checkRow, z + 1).Value Then
'                ws.Cells(checkRow, headerColumn).Value = ""
'                Exit For
'            End If
'        End If
        'if any column is blank delete the header
        If ws.Cells(checkRow, z).Value <> "" Then
            allEmpty = False
            'Exit For
        End If
        'if all are the same, delete header
        If z + 1 <= LC3 Then
            If ws.Cells(checkRow, z).Value <> ws.Cells(checkRow, z + 1).Value Then
                allTheSame = False
            End If
        End If
    Next z
    If allTheSame Or allEmpty Then
        ws.Cells(checkRow, headerColumn).Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: the issues right now is when I run my codes or the codes you modify, no matter if I have data (same) or not, I will always delete my header which is incorrect.

Comment: thats because you delete the header with ws.Cells(15, 2).Value = ""... what do you want to do in the loop?

Comment: I am just trying to check and see if cells across row 15 from column c has the same value or not and if so I want to delete the header....if not I want to keep it.

Comment: At the moment the program looks at all the cells in row 15 from column 3. It checks if on of them equals the next one. In every case that this is true the "rowheader" (15,2) gets deleted...

Comment: I want to check if all values in row 15 from column C is the same if so, I want to delete header if not I want to keep the header. In another word, if I have the same data or no data in row 15 from column C, I want to delete the header, else, keep the header.

Comment: so you want to delete it when 1. C15=D15=E15=F15=G15...? and 2. All is empty

Comment: yes so if I have the same data or no data, I want to delete the header only, and else, keep the header. So if I have C15=D15.... or blanks, I want to delete the header, else, keep it. Thanks

Comment: I edited the code and did some different cases... As I still don't understand it to the end... you can choose now :) Is that ok?

Comment: ok. obviously we have to watch if it is not the last one that we compare... edited the code again.

Comment: well, I don't... Do you know how to debug code? LC3 should be 3 in this case... go through the code step by step by hitting "F8" and search for the mistake. look at the values of the variables.

Comment: Ok. last try... now it deletes the header if all values are the same or if any value is empty... I think by changing the code a little bit you can do the rest...

Comment: Now with this lastlast try your wishes should be fulfilled... instructions were unclear ^^

Comment: Thank you for being patient, this is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
 If Application.Worksheetfunction.CountA("C" & z & ":Z" & z) = 0 then

'Row z has no entries between C and Z
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not working. When I have nothing from column C, the header is still there which I want to delete.